# Как перенаправить все запросы на index.php?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, маршрутизация, редирект

Подскажите как направить все запросы на index.php Apache сервера?
Мой .htaccess выглядит так:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

При обращении к site.ru/doc (которого нет), выдает 404. Как можно исправить это?

Я делаю URL manager, в котором прописываю правила маскирования URL.То есть я пропишу правила, которые при /doc/ должны вызывать контроллер нужный. В index файле я вызываю инициализацию роутера, где и делаю проверки по регулярным выражениям этих правил.

Comment: А что придумывать, вроде норм. Только после RewriteEngine On поставьте RewriteBase /

Comment: @KirillKorushkin при обращении к несуществующей странице выдает 404, то есть index.php не отрабатывает

Answer (score 0):

Глупая ошибка, но в настройках не был включен:

```
<Directory "/path/to/document/root/">
  AllowOverride All
  Allow from All
</Directory>
```